# AS3 Flash printJob print blank page

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printing

I just want to know that printing problem with action script 3 in flash web.

I have two movie clips one of them has a bitmap image, the other is used in purpose for size of paper.

I try to print this work but I've got blank paper always.
What's wrong in my code?

```
var printJob:PrintJob = new PrintJob();

//stage.stageWidth = 2481;
//stage.stageHeight = 3508;

mc.width = 980; // mc is a paper
mc.height = 700;

mc.x = mc.y = 0;

mc.addChild(content_mc);
content_mc.x = 10; // content_mc is a movie clip has a bitmap
content_mc.y = 10;

addChild(content_mc);

if (printJob.start()) {

    if (mc.width>printJob.pageWidth) {
        mc.width=printJob.pageWidth;
        mc.scaleY=mc.scaleX;
    }

    var rect1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 980, 700); 

    printJob.addPage(mc,rect1);
    printJob.send();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too easy to spot:

```
mc.addChild(content_mc);
addChild(content_mc);
```

Maybe you have done this on purpose thinking that you can add a DisplayObject in different places at the same time. Well no you can't, a DisplayObject can only belong to one display list at any one point. You can add it to as many display list as you want the last addChild will be the one that matters. In your case here, you add the content to the mc but you then remove it right away by adding it to another display list.

What you need is to add it to mc, then print, then add it back to where it should be. What you do is add it to mc, add it back to where it should be, then print so of course it's blank.

```
mc.addChild(content_mc);
content_mc.x = 10; 
content_mc.y = 10;
if (printJob.start()) 
{
     if (mc.width>printJob.pageWidth)
     {
         mc.width=printJob.pageWidth;
         mc.scaleY=mc.scaleX;
     }
     var rect1:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 980, 700); 
     printJob.addPage(mc,rect1);
     printJob.send();
} 
addChild(content_mc);
```

Comment: That's greate job :) Thank you very much